# how to print out array elements than using print_r();?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print out array elements from my custom function. Here is the fucntion :

```
$input = $_POST["input"];

function preprocessing($input){
   $input = trim(strtolower($input));
   $remove = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/s';
   $result = preg_split($remove, $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

   for($i = 0; $i < count($resultl); $i++){
      $result[$i] = trim($result[$i]);
   }
   return $result;
}
```

This is the input (example) : qwd qwd qwdqd123 13#$%^&*) ADDA ''''

I use print_r(preprocessing($input)); to print the array contents.

Output : Array ( [0] => qwd [1] => qwd [2] => qwdqd123 [3] => 13 [4] => adda )

Is there any method to customize the output ?
I want to make the output looks like this (my expectation) : 
1 qwd 
2 qwd 
3 qwdqd123 
4 13 
5 adda

Thanks before.

Comment: Just make a custom output function. That is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function printArray($result) {
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        echo ($key + 1), ' ', $value, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```